int64_t can't accomodate an actual result of subtraction
I know that if I need to substract one 32-bit number from another, as a result vairable I should use 64-bit type.
E.g.
uint32_t a = 1, b = 3123456789;
int diff = a - b;

is wrong because diff cannot accomodate the result.
But I can't understand how my code snippet works.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
        uint32_t a = 123;
        uint32_t b = 260000;
        int64_t diff = a - b;
        int diff2 = a - b;

        printf("DIFF:%ld\n", diff);
        printf("DIFF:%" PRId64 "\n", diff);

        printf("DIFF2:%d\n", diff2);

        if(diff < 0)
                puts("OK");

        if(diff2 < 0)
                puts("OK2");

        return 0;
}

Why the right answer is in diff2 and not in diff? How the .. big signed integer cannot contain an actual substraction result of two smaller unsigned integers?
OUTPUT:
DIFF:4294707419
DIFF:4294707419
DIFF2:-259877
OK2


Your subtraction is being performed on uint32_t which can never produce a negative result. So it is a big positive number. This is then being promoted to int64_t

The expression a - b yields an uint32_t.  Whatever garbage you get, you get it right there. The fact that you then assign that uint32_t to an int64_t diff does diddly squat to fix the garbage.

@budoattack, If int is 64-bit, then a - b will be a negative number.  Much more likely a - b is unsigned subtraction and never results in a negative difference.

@budoattack, avoid printf("DIFF:%ld\n", diff); as the specifier and type may not match.  printf("DIFF:%" PRId64 "\n", diff); is best.


I know that if I need to substract one 32-bit number from another, as a result variable I should use 64-bit type.

Yes, that is true that the subtraction needs to use math wider than 32-bit.  Yet OP's code did not certainly use wider math.
uint32_t a = 123;
uint32_t b = 260000;
int64_t diff = a - b; // 32-bit subtraction.

Unless an int is wider than uint32_t (quite unlikely), a - b uses uint32_t math.  To use wider math in the subtraction, insure wider math is used.
Notice the type of diff, the object where the difference is saved is irrelevant to the type of the difference.
// All below use at least 64-bit signed math for the subtraction.
(int64_t) a - b
(int64_t) a - (int64_t) b
0LL + a - b
#include <stdint.h>
INT64_C(0) + a - b

// Example that avoids casts.
int64_t diff = 0LL + a - b;


C2X is planned to have typeof() which allows code to affect the right-hand side of the expression with the type of the left-hand side.  Given operator precedence, the subtraction uses int64_t math.
uint32_t a = 123;
uint32_t b = 260000;
int64_t diff = (typeof(diff))a - b;


Sorry but don't quite understand the difference between 64-bit math and 32-bit math.. Why (int64_t) a - (int64_t) b is something different from (int32_t) a - (int32_t) b? Of course in case where a and b are 32-bit initially

@budoattack (int32_t) a - (int32_t) b can only generate 2^32 different results or undefined behavior on overflow.  (int64_t) a - (int64_t) b can generate about 2^33 different results.  Consider a == INT32_MIN, b == 1.

Even though you used a - b as initialization, the subtraction still happens as an unsigned. Spelling things out explicitly, you get
int64_t diff = int64_t(uint32_t(a) - uint32_t(b));
int diff2 = int(uint32_t(a) - uint32_t(b));

Now, unsigned arithmetic is modular, so when you get a negative result, it wraps around to a large number, 2^32 + 123 - 260000 to be precise.
When you convert this uint32_t value to an int64_t, it fits, and you get the same value.
When you convert this uint32_t value to an int, it doesn't fit, and you wrap around again, back to being 123 - 260000†. If you check modular arithmetic carefully, you'll find that addition, subtraction and multiplication (but not division) on unsigned and signed types of the same width behaves "nicely", in the sense that you can freely convert back and forth and still get the same result.
However, a quirk of C and C++ means that while you are allowed to let signed integers wrap around for conversions, you are not allowed to let signed integers wrap around directly, e.g.
int i = 1 << 30;
i *= 2;     // undefined behavior

unsigned u = 1u << 31;
int j = u;  // implementation-defined, j is practically always -2^31

† Technically, implementation-defined in C and C++ prior C++20, but practically always true. 

Sorry, but don't quite understand "while you are allowed to let signed integers wrap around for conversions, you are not allowed to let signed integers wrap around directly, e.g." - it means that signed integer overflow like int diff2 = uint32_t(a) - uint32_t(b); is not UB but int diff2 = uint32_t(1 << 30) * 2; is UB? I thought that every signed overflow is UB.. Or what you mean by "you can freely convert back and forth and still get the same result"

You mentioned that "addition, subtraction and multiplication" are OK for signed overflow. Did I get it right? So your first example with UB is multiplication overflow ._. Sorry for the stupid questions

@budoattack I meant int(1u << 31) is fine, but 1 << 31 is not. Converting from a value out of range is fine, but overflowing with arithmetic is not.

What you are currently doing is subtracting two uint32_ts. The u stands for unsigned. When you operate on two unsigned integers, you get an unsigned integer. In this case it is a large positive number.
When you assign it to int64_t it can fit the large positive number and hence shows a positive result. int however cannot fit that large positive number and you get a negative number which happens to be correct. The correct way to do this would be -
int64_t diff = (int64_t)a - (int64_t)b;

"When you operate on two unsigned integers, you get an unsigned integer." --> not always as unsigned char - unsigned char usually results in an int.  It is the types after the usual integer promotions that counts.
